# Syntax Error in a Labeled Loop in MySQL

Tags: mysql, loops

I have the following query that loops over chunks of data and copy it to another table. One of my goals for using label is to have a mechanism to exit from the loop once some condition are met:

```
SET @nth = 0;
SET @size = 1000 * 1;
SET @offset = @nth * @size;
SET @count = 7120;

lable1: LOOP
    PREPARE select_stmt FROM 
    "INSERT INTO foo.`track_new` (
        `...`
    )
    SELECT 
        `...`
    FROM foo.`track`  a
    WHERE ...
    ORDER BY ...
    LIMIT ?, ?";

    EXECUTE select_stmt USING @offset, @size; 

    IF @offset + @size > @count THEN LEAVE lable1;
    END IF;

    ...

END LOOP;
```

but I am getting these errors (messages for successful queries were removed):

```
Query: lable1: LOOP PREPARE select_stmt FROM "INSERT INTO gps.`track_new` (         `id`,       `unit_id`,      `gps_time`,         `added_when`,       `latit...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'lable1: LOOP
    PREPARE select_stmt FROM 
    "INSERT INTO gps.`track_new` (
        `id`,
' at line 1

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0 sec
--------------------------------------------------
...

Query: IF @offset + @size > @count THEN leave lable1

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF @offset + @size > @count THEN leave lable1' at line 1

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0 sec
--------------------------------------------------
```

I have already checked for the syntax of label and it seems fine.
I have also checked for the syntax for loops and other control structures in mysql but I can't figure what's wrong.

**EDIT:**

I have noticed that the line `EXECUTE select_stmt USING @offset, @size;` gets executed but the Loop does not repeat afterwards.

Comment: Is this code in a procedure?

Comment: Nope, its a plain query. I haven't considered putting it inside a procedure yet. Is it illegal to run if not put inside a procedure?

Comment: Yes, loops have to be in procedures (or functions and possibly triggers)